# 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

Here is my code:

```
 from fastapi import (FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, UploadFile, 
                    File, Form, Depends, HTTPException, status, Request)
from tortoise.contrib.fastapi import register_tortoise
from models import (User, Business, Product, user_pydantic, user_pydanticIn, 
                    product_pydantic,product_pydanticIn, business_pydantic, 
                    business_pydanticIn, user_pydanticOut)

# signals
from tortoise.signals import  post_save 
from typing import List, Optional, Type
from tortoise import BaseDBAsyncClient

from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from starlette.requests import Request

#authentication and authorization 
import jwt
from dotenv import dotenv_values
from fastapi.security import (
    OAuth2PasswordBearer,
    OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
)
# self packages
from emails import *
from authentication import *
from dotenv import dotenv_values
import math

# user image uploads
#  pip install python-multipart
from fastapi import File, UploadFile
import secrets
# static files
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

# pillow
from PIL import Image

# templates
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

# HTMLResponse
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

config_credentials = dict(dotenv_values(".env"))


app = FastAPI()

# static files
# pip install aiofiles
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

# authorization configs
oath2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl = 'token')

# password helper functions
@app.post('/token')
async def generate_token(request_form: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    token = await token_generator(request_form.username, request_form.password)
    return {'access_token' : token, 'token_type' : 'bearer'}



# process signals here
@post_save(User)
async def create_business(
    sender: "Type[User]",
    instance: User,
    created: bool,
    using_db: "Optional[BaseDBAsyncClient]",
    update_fields: List[str]) -> None:
    
    if created:
        business_obj = await Business.create(
                business_name = instance.username, owner = instance)
        await business_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(business_obj)
        # send email functionality
        await send_email([instance.email], instance)


@app.post('/registration')
async def user_registration(user: user_pydanticIn):
    user_info = user.dict(exclude_unset = True)
    user_info['password'] = get_password_hash(user_info['password'])
    user_obj = await User.create(**user_info)
    new_user = await user_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(user_obj)
 
    return {"status" : "ok", 
            "data" : 
                f"Hello {new_user.username} thanks for choosing our services. Please check your email inbox and click on the link to confirm your registration."}



# template for email verification
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get('/verification',  response_class=HTMLResponse)
# make sure to import request from fastapi and HTMLResponse
async def email_verification(request: Request, token: str):
    user = await verify_token(token)
    if user and not user.is_verified:
        user.is_verified = True
        await user.save()
        return templates.TemplateResponse("verification.html", 
                                {"request": request, "username": user.username}
                        )
    raise HTTPException(
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail = "Invalid or expired token",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oath2_scheme)):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, config_credentials['SECRET'], algorithms = ['HS256'])
        user = await User.get(id = payload.get("id"))
    except:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail = "Invalid username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )

    return await user

@app.post('/user/me')
async def user_login(user: user_pydantic = Depends(get_current_user)):

    business = await Business.get(owner = user)
    logo = business.logo
    logo = "localhost:8000/static/images/"+logo

    return {"status" : "ok", 
            "data" : 
                {
                    "username" : user.username,
                    "email" : user.email,
                    "verified" : user.is_verified,
                    "join_date" : user.join_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"),
                    "logo" : logo
                }
            }


@app.post("/products")
async def add_new_product(product: product_pydanticIn, 
                            user: user_pydantic = Depends(get_current_user)):
    product = product.dict(exclude_unset = True)
    # to avoid division by zero error
    if product['original_price'] > 0:
        product["percentage_discount"] = ((product["original_price"] - product['new_price'] )/ product['original_price']) * 100

    product_obj = await Product.create(**product, business = user)
    product_obj = await product_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(product_obj)
    return {"status" : "ok", "data" : product_obj}


@app.get("/products")
async def get_products():
    response = await product_pydantic.from_tortoise_orm(Product.all())
    return {"status" : "ok", "data" : response}


@app.get("/products/{id}")
async def specific_product(id: int):
    product = await Product.get(id = id)
    business = await product.business
    owner = await business.owner
    response = await product_pydantic.from_queryset_single(Product.get(id = id))
    print(type(response))
    return {"status" : "ok",
            "data" : 
                    {
                        "product_details" : response,
                        "business_details" : {
                            "name" : business.business_name,
                            "city" : business.city,
                            "region" : business.region,
                            "description" : business.business_description,
                            "logo" : business.logo,
                            "owner_id" : owner.id,
                            "email" : owner.email,
                            "join_date" :  owner.join_date.strftime("%b %d %Y")
                        }
                    }
            }


@app.delete("/products/{id}")
async def delete_product(id: int, user: user_pydantic = Depends(get_current_user)):
    product = await Product.get(id = id)
    business =  await product.business
    owner = await business.owner
    if user == owner:
        product.delete()
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail = "Not authenticated to perform this action",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    return {"status" : "ok"}


# image upload
@app.post("/uploadfile/profile")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...), 
                                user: user_pydantic = Depends(get_current_user)):
    FILEPATH = "./static/images/"
    filename = file.filename
    extension = filename.split(".")[1]

    if extension not in ["jpg", "png"]:
        return {"status" : "error", "detail" : "file extension not allowed"}

    token_name = secrets.token_hex(10)+"."+extension
    generated_name = FILEPATH + token_name
    file_content = await file.read()
    with open(generated_name, "wb") as file:
        file.write(file_content)


    # pillow
    img = Image.open(generated_name)
    img = img.resize(size = (200,200))
    img.save(generated_name)

    file.close()

    business = await Business.get(owner = user)
    owner = await business.owner

 # check if the user making the request is authenticated
    print(user.id)
    print(owner.id)
    if owner == user:
        business.logo = token_name
        await business.save()
    
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail = "Not authenticated to perform this action",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    file_url = "localhost:8000" + generated_name[1:]
    return {"status": "ok", "filename": file_url}


@app.post("/uploadfile/product/{id}")
# check for product owner before making the changes.
async def create_upload_file(id: int, file: UploadFile = File(...), 
                                user: user_pydantic = Depends(get_current_user)):
    FILEPATH = "./static/images/"
    filename = file.filename
    extension = filename.split(".")[1]

    if extension not in ["jpg", "png"]:
        return {"status" : "error", "detail" : "file extension not allowed"}

    token_name = secrets.token_hex(10)+"."+extension
    generated_name = FILEPATH + token_name
    file_content = await file.read()
    with open(generated_name, "wb") as file:
        file.write(file_content)


    # pillow
    img = Image.open(generated_name)
    img = img.resize(size = (200,200))
    img.save(generated_name)

    file.close()

    #get product details
    product = await Product.get(id = id)
    business = await product.business
    owner = await business.owner

    # check if the user making the request is authenticated
    if owner == user:
        product.product_image = token_name
        await product.save()
    
    else:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
            detail = "Not authenticated to perform this action",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )


    file_url = "localhost:8000" + generated_name[1:]
    return {"status": "ok", "filename": file_url}




register_tortoise(
    app,
    db_url='sqlite://database.sqlite3',
    modules={'models': ['models']},
    generate_schemas = True,
    add_exception_handlers = True
)
```

When im opening up http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs and try the "/registration" request I get the error: Code: 422 Details: Error: Unprocessable Entity`

Response body:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [],
      "msg": "UNIQUE constraint failed: user.username",
      "type": "IntegrityError"
    }
  ]
}
```

Response headers:

```
 content-length: 95  
 content-type: application/json  
 date: Sun,04 Dec 2022 23:22:02 GMT  
 server: uvicorn
```

And in the console I get:

```
127.0.0.1:54566 - "POST /registration HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

After some debugging I think that the line 86

```
user_obj = await User.create(**user_info)
```

Is causing problems, but I can't seem to be able to fix the issue. Feel free to ask for any additional information

UPD: I was followng Princekrampah's guide on youtube, the git link to the repo is: https://github.com/Princekrampah/learningFastAPI/tree/master/shoppingAPI

Comment: What fields "user_pydanticIn" requires?

Comment: This is my User class:
```class User(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk = True, index = True)
    username = fields.CharField(max_length = 20, null = False, unique = True)
    email = fields.CharField(max_length = 200, null = False, unique = True)
    password = fields.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False)
    is_verified = fields.BooleanField(default = False)
    join_date = fields.DatetimeField(default = datetime.utcnow)
```
user_pydantic is: ```user_pydanticIn = pydantic_model_creator(User, name = "UserIn", exclude_readonly = True, exclude=("is_verified", 'join_date'))```

Comment: This looks like a database error - you have the username in it and because you set it to unique=True in your model you see the error.